# How To Use Ajax To Retrieve My Data From a PHP File (Using JQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use an Ajax call using JQuery on my html page to retrieve the data field 'Page' which is stored using PHP.

I would like to retrieve $Page from the input.php or alternatively $f1 from the output.php ( this is the same data). and put this data into the div id="menu" a href containers e.g. id="homebox".

I have made an attempt at the Ajax call but I need some advice on what parameters to put into it.

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"output.php", // Or insert.php ?
data: // I am not sure what to put in here, 
success: function( data ){
alert(data);
return;
}
});
```

Here's my code from the three files:

insert.php:

```
$ID=$_POST['ID'];
$Page=$_POST['Page'];
$Description=$_POST['Description'];

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = ("INSERT INTO Pages (ID, Page, Description)
VALUES 
('$ID','$Page','$Description')");

mysql_query($query);
```

output.php:

```
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM Pages";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Page</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Description</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Page");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Description");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() 
{

$('#homebox').click(function() 
{  
$('ul:first a').filter(function(i) { return $.trim($(this).text()) == '';   }).first().text('Home')
$('#headingtochange').html('Home');
$('#paragraphtochange').html('The user is currently on the Home page.');
});
});
</script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="homebox">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="kuwebsitebox">KU Website</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="studyspacebox">StudySpace</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="osisbox">OSIS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="librarybox">Library</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="studenthubbox">StudentHUB</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var params = {'action': 'save' , 'id':5};
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url:"output.php", // Or insert.php ?
data: params , 
success: function( data ){
alert(data);
return;
}
});
```

Comment: or he could use a serialized string for the data, doesn't have to be a json object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however, this only brings up a dialogue box of all the output.php code. Is there any way to select only the Page fields content ($f1)?

Comment: remove alert(data) from the code. and add a div with some id="out_put" for example.
then add  $('#out_put').html(data);  insted of alert.
let me know if any issue.
thanks

Comment: Thanks, that's more what I wanted, however I only want to show the $Page / $f1 value from my PHP file. Would that be done by changing the params?

Comment: you can do 
echo json_encode(array('page' => $page, 'f1' => $f1))

from the php file. then you can use those data in the ajax call response as data.page  or data.f1

thanks

Comment: I have added the json array to my php file but I cannot get it to show from my $.ajax call, the array is called $pageArray. Here's the JQuery code I have added:                                     success: function( data.f1 ){
$("#paragraphtochange").html(data.f1);

Comment: success:function(data){
$("#paragraphtochange").html(data.f1);
}

Comment: The data.f1 still does not appear, is it because it is a json object and I am not using the $.get_json call? Or should it still work inside the $.ajax call?

Comment: try to trace data and see what you are getting in the ajax call response

Comment: data displays everything that is in my output.php file. This shows it is working, however I only want to show the Page data. Maybe it is my array in the php file that is the problem: <?php
$pageArray = array( 'f1' => $f1);
                    
echo json_encode($pageArray);
?>

Comment: there sud not be any other output other than this $pagearray.
all u sud put under $f1.   
i think there are other html contents thats why its cretaing problem.

Comment: Yes there are html contents in my output.php file which display a table, but that shouldn't matter if I am pointing to data.f1? Also how would I be able to only display the array?

Comment: your have to understand that your html content along with what ever you output as $pageArray is considered as data.
so data.f1 wont mean anything. else use different file which has no other html content other than the $pageArray

Comment: I have made another php file that outputs only the Page data. How can I iterate through this data to show 1 Page data for every div container? e.g. I have $("#firstbox").html(data); but I want to only display 1 page here and the next Page data in $("#secondbox").html(data);

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), for example:

```
$('#paragraphtochange').load( 'output.php');
```

It also allows you to change title (as part of callback `oncomplete`) with simple code as this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='_page_title' value='Home' />
```

With (in oncomplete callback):

```
$('#headingtochange').html( $( 'input[name=_page_title]').val()).
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the .load() method seems to do what I want, however is there any way to only load the Page field's content without loading the whole table?

Comment: @user1199649 the easiest way would be to write `$('#page').load('script/that/generates/only/page.php')`

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, however if I wanted to output 1 Page value in 1 href and then the same for the next Page value. How could I select only 1 value for each href?

Comment: @user1199649 huh? Add examples what you need to do, I didn't get it. :-/

Comment: I want 1 $Page value to go into 1 href and then the next and so on: <li><a href="#" id="homebox">$firstPagevalue</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="kuwebsitebox">$secondPagevalue</a></li> The Page values are from $f1 in the output.php